# Consent Management for End Users

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, consent-management

I was looking to implement the Consent MGMT Installed Package from Salesforce Labs into our ecosystem since it has a well-built screenflow. However the issue is, I'd like to add and remove certain forms of consent that they offer, and modify the flow a bit. Since this is a a managed package, all those contents are hidden, unfortunately.

Has anyone else found a good solution for Sales/Customer Service/Marketing teams help track consent? Im looking for a good mechanism like a screen flow or buttons.

Comment: [Preference Manager](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/preference-manager-quick-look), part of Privacy Center (paid add-on).

Answer (score 0):

All the metadata for the package is available on GitHub at https://github.com/schandlergarcia/consent-capture/tree/master

Comment: You are a lifesaver!